# Compile ImageMagick on heroku with webp delegate

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, webp

I'd like to compile imagemagick on heroku and allow webp support. I can build and install webp from source, but I can't write it to /usr/local/.. because herokus filesystem is readonly.

I've built webp and installed it to /tmp/webp.

After downloading the imagemagick tarball, I try to compile it with webp support but it can't find the webp installation (understandably so).

Can I run configure with an argument that will allow it to find my webp installation?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check the Heroku build pack you are using.  They contain ImageMagick and WepP is a standard extension for Imagemagick